# Solve Recurrence relation using master theorem method

Tags: algorithm, recurrence, master-theorem

So, I have

> T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n^2

And I found a = 2, b = 2, and f(n) = n^2, and to get n^2 I used case 3 for the master theorem which is

> **f(n) = big Omega ( n ^ logba + E )**

and I found **big Omega (n^2)**

So, how can I solve

> **big theta ( big Omega (n^2) ) ?**

Also, is my calculations correct?

Comment: yes, you are correct.

Comment: you can't solve `big theta ( big Omega (n^2) )`, since omega and theta describe boundaries and are not actual concrete functions, therefore you got something wrong by getting to the term `big theta ( big Omega (n^2) )`

Comment: @DuDa In the formula I have it's written as " big theta ( f(n) ) " and I got "f(n) = big omega (n^2)". Am I using the wrong formula? or is the answer is already "big omega (n^2)"

Comment: `f(n) = big theta ( g(n) )`  is a general writing of `f(n) ∈ big theta ( g(n) )`. So you can't do the arithmetics you are used to do. I'm not that familiar with the master theorem, I'll have a look into it.

Comment: So regarding wikipedia the conclusion is, that `T(n)` is in `Big Theta (f(n))`. Meaning your time complexitiy has an upper bound of something like`f(n)`and a lower bound of something like `f(n)`. So your time complexity is square in the worst and best case (`f(n)=n^2`). You can't compute concrete values with the master theorem, "just" bounds.

Comment: @DuDa That clears my confusion, thanks a lot